# Querying MYSQL within a class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have a shopping basket class and want to query my database within it but cannot get my head around it.

I only want to connect to the database upon construct and close the connection upon destruct.

Surely I don't need to make a new connection for each query I call within the class?

Plus I would prefer to use mysqli

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about this http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/8/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-4-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick example of what you could do:

```
class ShoppingBasket{

    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getBasketItems(){
        return $this->db->query("SELECT id, name, price FROM shopping_basket");
    }

}

$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$shoppingBasket = new ShoppingBasket($db);
$items = $shoppingBasket->getBasketItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to pass a DB connection or DB abstraction object to your constructor (dependency injection) and not worry about trying to add DB instantiation logic to your class.